# How to set the language for the whole session after login in Django

Tags: django, internationalization, translation, django-login

I'm stuck, trying to set the language for an entire session, so that the menus, forms, etc. are displayed according to the language entered during login.

For this I have defined the following:

In the settings.py file add the middleware:

`'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',`

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

Also add the context renderer:
`'django.template.context_processors.i18n'`

And I defined my 3 languages:

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'es'

LANGUAGES = [
    ('es' _('Spanish')),
    ('en', _ ('English')),
    ('it', _ ('Italian')),
]
```

This is my view:

```
class LoginFormView(FormView):
    form_class = UserLoginForm
    template_name = 'login.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('index')

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(self.success_url)
        return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        login(self.request, form.get_user())
        user_language = self.request.POST.get('language', None)
        translation.activate(user_language)
        self.request.session['django_language'] = user_language
        self.request.session[translation.LANGUAGE_SESSION_KEY] = user_language
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.success_url)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['title'] = 'Iniciar sesión'
        return context
```

Despite this, the language after login does not change and always remains in Spanish.

All templates have the tag:

```
{% load i18n %}
```

I also tried to force the language change by placing a button in the navigation bar, in order to test if the translation works and **is indeed working well**:

```
<button type="button" class="btn-shadow p-1 btn btn-primary btn-sm">
  {% include 'change_language.html' %}
  <i class="fa text-white fa-calendar pr-1 pl-1"></i>
</button>
```

change_language.html

```
 {% load i18n %}
    <form action="/i18n/setlang/" method="post" style="display: inline;">
    {% csrf_token %}
      <div style="display: inline;">
        <select name="language" onchange="javascript:form.submit()">
          {% for lang in LANGUAGES %}
            <option value="{{ lang.0 }}"{% ifequal LANGUAGE_CODE lang.0 %} selected="selected"{% endifequal %}>{{ lang.1 }}</option>
          {% endfor %}
        </select>
      </div>
    </form>
```

Therefore, I do not know if the code that I am putting in the form_valid() is correct and if it should go there.